# Dynamic Picklist on a WorkItem

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to have dynamic Picklists based on selected values in the Cloud Services Version of Devops?

For example, on a WorkiItem, if Option 1 is selected in Picklist A, then Picklist B has Options A, B & C and then if Option 2 is selected in Picklist A, Picklist B has options A & C?

I didn't see any way to create a Rule around this scenario and I have tried searching the documentation but couldn't find a definitive answer.  If not possible to do via Rule, is it possible to do it via the REST API? (I don't think it can, as I have only been able to build customization's after a WorkItem has been been saved, not while it was being edited.)

I have a feeling that this is not possible, but looking to see if

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that`s not possible in the current processes.

That was in the old TFS process model.